# Windows multi-monitor setup with seperated taskbars and alt-tabbing

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, taskbar, alt-tab

I've found UltraMon and several other tools that will provide seperated taskbars, but is there a tool that will also seperate alt-tabbing behaviour for all monitors?

Would be nice if it worked for XP and Win7